# Input file path from console

Tags: c#, csv

I want to load a csv from my computer, but want specify the path via user input, not hardcoded(like `new StreamReader(@"C:/text.csv")`)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Console.ReadLine()))
    { 
    }
}
```

My question is what is the right way to input the path on the console?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: `C:/text.csv` or `C:\text.csv` should both work. Didn't you try?

Comment: Console lets me input filepath but after that it shows this: Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path denied.

Comment: it looks like you don't have the rights to acces your `C` hardrive

Comment: @itsme86 thanks, I just had to replace \ witch /. Silly me!

Comment: You might have to elevate your application permissions, or store them in a public user folder or your user folder and just use: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserFolder)`.  I think it's called that, but either way that or `ProgramData` would work.

Comment: @SvetoslavKepchelev You're sanitizing the data you enter correct?